# Is there a way to cipher in java/kotlin and decipher in nodejs with AES/CBC?

Tags: java, android, node.js, cryptography, kotlin

I try to cipher a text in java and decipher it in nodejs (and vice versa)

I can cipher and decipher in the same language but I can't with them both ...

Here is my code in Kotlin :

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun encrypt(text: String, password: String?): String?
{
    if (password == null)
        return null

    val hash = toHash(password).copyOf(16)
    val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(hash, "AES")
    val ivSpec = IvParameterSpec(hash)
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec)

    val results = cipher.doFinal(text.toByteArray())

    return Base64.encodeToString(results, Base64.NO_WRAP or Base64.DEFAULT)

}

@Throws(Exception::class)
fun decrypt(text: String, password: String?): String?
{
    if (password == null)
        return null

    val hash = toHash(password).copyOf(16)
    val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(hash, "AES")
    val ivSpec = IvParameterSpec(hash)
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec)

    return String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT)))
}
```

And here is my code in JS :

```
function decrypt(data, password)
{
    var hash = sha256(password).substring(0, 16)
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', hash, hash);
    var dec = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf8');
    dec += decipher.final('utf8');
    return dec;
}

function encrypt(data, password)
{
    var hash = sha256(password).substring(0, 16)
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', hash, hash);
    var crypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'hex');
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return crypted;
}
```

I have tried to play with the differents block size in Java and nodeJS (192, 128 and 256) but it's not working.
I don't want to cipher in ECB, I want to achive this in CBC or CTR.

Does someone know how to do this please ? Thank you per advance !

Comment: Your Kotlin code uses `Base64` for encoding/decoding for `byte[]<->String`, however on Node.js side you define that it should be treated as `hex`. I don't think that this will ever work.

Comment: You need to use the same encoding for each, check the documentation for each. Many "new" languages want to gloss over binary in favor of strings but many things are essentially binary such as encryption and there Internet. So you have to figure this out for each language and encryption implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried using cbc,noPadding and applied same padding algorithm in both js and java and worked fine it generated same encrypted string in js and java as well please check the link:

JS link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/aihF54rkxxw3Jjcly9Uo?p=preview

Java code:

```
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.*;

public class CipherConversion {

    private static final String algorithm = "AES/CBC/NoPadding";

    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    private static final byte[] ivValue = new byte[] { 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0' };

    private static final IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(ivValue);
    private static final SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");

   // final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    private static String padString(String source) {
        char paddingChar = ' ';
        int size = 16;
        int x = source.length() % size;
        int padLength = size - x;

        for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)
        {
            source += paddingChar;
        }
        return source;
      }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("keyValue"+keyValue);
        System.out.println("keyValue"+ivValue);
        String password = "ChangeMe1";
        String passwordEnc = CipherConversion.encrypt(padString(password));
        String passwordDec = CipherConversion.decrypt(passwordEnc);

        System.out.println("Plain Text : " + password);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + passwordEnc);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + passwordDec);
    }

}
```

Comment: Its a class imported from sun.misc as sun.misc.BASE64Decoder used to convert base64 encoded data into binary data.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar situation before, where the AES encryption was not working for both application and server side. Finally, I could make it work for both Android and server side. I am providing the class that I used for AES encryption. However, I have a java implementation and I thought that would be a help.

```
import android.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESProvider {
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String ENCRYPTION_KEY = "YourEncryptionKey";

    public static String encrypt(String stringToEncrypt) {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(ENCRYPTION_KEY, ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] data = cipher.doFinal(stringToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }

    public static String decrypt(String stringToDecrypt) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(ENCRYPTION_KEY, ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(stringToDecrypt, Base64.DEFAULT)));
    }
}
```

I was missing the Base64 encode and decode while encoding and decoding the AES encryption in my case. Hope that helps!